# Javascript OR statement always true

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to check to see if the user is **not** logged into Wordpress (body would contain class 'logged-in') OR if the user is not on the **my-resources** section (foo.co.uk/my-resources/). If either fails I want the else statement to kick in.

However my code ***always*** comes back as true:

```
if(!$('body').hasClass('logged-in') || (document.location.href.indexOf('/my-resources/') === -1))
{
    console.log ( 'DO SOMETHING. The user is not logged in or in my resources' );
}
else
{
    console.log ( 'DO NOTHING. The user is logged in or in my resources' );
}
```

Comment: So console.log the values of `$('body').hasClass('logged-in')` and `document.location.href.indexOf('/my-resources/')` to see what you are actually getting.

Comment: When is `if` called within `js` ?

Comment: I'm always seeing the "DO SOMETHING" statement even if the user is logged in. However I am now seeing the correct "DO NOTHING" statement on the my-resources section.

Comment: Singularly both IF statements work, combining them ends with a false positive on user who are logged in but not in the 'my-resources' section. (console reports 'DO SOMETHING').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with a logic error. The `else` statement only executes when the negation of the `if` condition is true. The negation of your condition is that the user is both logged in and on /my-resources/. From the question, you want your `else` branch to execute when the user is either logged in or in /my-resources/. Change your if statement to the negation of this else condition, which is the user is not logged in and the user is not in /my-resources/. (just change the `||` to `&&`):

```
if(!$('body').hasClass('logged-in') && (document.location.href.indexOf('/my-resources/') === -1))
```

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I was looking for.